# Setup ejabberd cluster by hand (without ejabberdctl join_cluster)

Tags: ejabberd

According to the docs at http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/clustering/#adding-a-node-in-a-cluster ejabberd clusters should be set up via the "join_cluster" command in ejaberdctl. However, there is currently a bug which prevents this from working (at least in my attempts): https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/676

Is there a clean way to setup the clustering by hand without relying on ejabberdctl? In such a way that nodes going offline/online will automatically re-join as needed?

(this isn't mission-critical for me since I'm just kicking the tires and testing things out, but it's good to know how things work as a backup plan and also to administrate the clustering with a more hands-on approach in case of fires that need putting out etc. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two choices:

- use `ejabberdctl join_cluster`
- do what `join_cluster` is doing manually. Old process was described in older version of the documentation: https://github.com/processone/docs.ejabberd.im/blob/d35aba1da482d5b83a8e314c9039e7613216190f/content/admin/guide/index.md#clustering

As you will see, the process is quite complex, so you really should find a way to have an approach based on `join_cluster` working.

Comment: Didn't realize that documentation goes over the manual process- Thanks! :)

Comment: It used to. It was in history of the document on Github.